# Postfix: Send email ok without attachment, times out with attachment

Tags: postfix, email-server

This appears to be only happening with one client.

I send an email without an attachment and it goes through fine all happy hunky dory, no issues what so ever.  This has worked previously (leading me to think there was an update on their end somewhere?  I have done nothing to change any settings on my servers).

I attach jpg images and send it, and there is a timeout.  What I found from wireshark is it appears the remote end is getting a dup ack and my server tries resending, resending again, etc. until the timeouts kick in.  (I upped the data_xfr and so on timeouts to 20 minutes just to make sure).  That hasn't helped.

They are telling me it is on my end.  I showed them the packets with the retransmissions and they are not responding.  I would like to be able to offer suggestions, or even get suggestions on what to try on my end.

The emails with attachments eventually time out, mailq says timed out while sending message body.

They tell me they don't see it trying to resend, and it doesn't finish the email sending.

Any help on where to troubleshoot or guide me in a direction is appreciated.  If there is need for more details I may have omitted, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like either an MTU problem or just maybe an in-line application firewall problem. If the packet that the remote end never acks is the first packet above say 1350 octets, then it is very probably an MTU problem. To check, you can try sending a long text without any attachment (several thousand bytes). If there have been same-sized (or even bigger) packets before that have been acked then it is not an MTU problem.

If the never-acked packet is the beginning or the end of the attachment, then it is probably an application firewall problem. Check if the remote server SMTP greeting is replaced by stars, that is a sure sign of some application firewall interfering. Cisco PIX is notorious for creating problems.

I haven't covered all the possibilities, but this should give you a good start!

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate the starting point and I will see if that leads me in the right direction.  I appreciate it.  I will let you know what I find out.

Comment: We have the MTU set to 1492 on the our firewall and on the server as well.  I tested and getting emails to external accounts.  I did send the long text file and it is smaller than the attachments but still 40KB in size and it appears to have gone through, but there is no attachment as i embedded the text in the email body.  That went through as far as I can tell, can't confirm as they aren't in the office right now.  Thanks, I am still working on it.  I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: It appears to have been the MTU.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Happy to have helped!